# Run an AppleScript from project when NSButton is clicked

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, applescript, nsbutton

I have an AppleScript that I have imported into my Xcode project correctly and I have also set up a `-(IBAction)` to handle when the user clicks the button however I am unable how to run an AppleScript when the button is clicked.

I would essentially like the script to run just as it would if it were opened via the Finder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"finder" ofType:@"scpt"];
NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSAppleScript* appleScript =[[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
[appleScript executeAndReturnError:nil];
```